# How to setup a method that takes an implicit parameter in scala using Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito

I am getting the familiar "Invalid use of argument matchers" trying to setup a method that takes a regular parameter and an implicit parameter.

```
trait MyLogger {
    def debug(msg: => Any)(implicit context: LoggingContext)
}

val implicit lc = EmptyLoggingContext
val myMock = mock[MyLogger]

when(myMock.debug(any())(any())).thenAnswer(
    new Answer[Unit]() {
        override def answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock): Unit = ???
    }
)
```

With the above, I get "2 matchers expected, 1 recorded"

If I change it to:

```
when(myMock.debug(any())).thenAnswer....
```

I don't get a matcher error, but the Answer override is never invoked.

I have also tried:

```
when(myMock.debug(any())(any(classOf[LoggingContext]))
```

which again gives the 2 matchers expected error.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:  The issue here turns out to be that msg is a by-name parameter which is not mockable in mockito